# Site collection Disaster Recovery?

Tags: 2007, wss-3.0, stsadm, administration, disaster-recovery

One of the Site collection Administrators has deleted the Site Collection mistakenly, so we want to restore it back. What would the best approach ?

Some of the SQL stuff:

- SQL Full backup -> Every day SQL
- Incremental backup -> Every hour

We have not implemented any SharePoint disaster recovery methods.

Comment: My favorite third party tool for this: http://www.metalogix.com/Products/Selective-Restore-Manager-for-SharePoint.aspx restores right from content database after you restore the db.  Disclaimer: I'm not affiliated with Metalogix, but regularly use their stuff.  Otherwise the designated answer is the best practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Restore the SQL DB containing the site collection
2. Create new web application (any host name or port will do)
3. Attach Content Database using

   `stsadm -o addcontentdb -url http://URLofWindowsSharePointServicesSite -databasename DatabaseName -databaseserver DatabaseServer`
4. You should be able to find your site collection in the web application
5. Using stsadm -o export -url [site-coll-new-url] -includeusersecurity -versions 4 export the full web application
6. Using stsadm -o import -url [site-coll-dest-url] -versions 2 import the site collection to your old web app.

Please verify the `stsadm -o export` and `stsadm -o import` syntax exactly. I am writing this off the top of my head.

**OR** you can try using [Appasure DocRetriever](http://www.sharepointreviews.com/component/content/article/66-sharepoint-backup-recovery/766-DocRetriever-Lite-by-AppAssure.html)